# Mediaelement.js poster

Tags: javascript, html, mediaelement.js

I'm working on mobile device . (iOS)

I use MediaElement.js to display my video. There is a poster on it :

```
<video id="player1" width="400" height="160" controls="control" preload="none" poster="Youtube.png">        
            <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lt6CUH9bVzI" type="video/youtube" />
        </video>
```

I want to click on the poster to play my video but it doesn't work. How can I do this ?

Here is the javascript code :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // declare object for video
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1');

});
</script>
```

Thanks